# Map marker getPosition() not working for google maps on first call of function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to place a marker on my map and then use the position of that marker to draw some polygons. However, marker.getPosition() does not seem to return a value initially. I would need to call the function again to get the previous marker position. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = fubar;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(1);
      if (marker == null){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
        });
      }
      marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
  });
  document.write(marker.getPosition());   //this displays nothing
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google maps is using callbacks, ([see parameter 2 in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder)) because its [not synchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O). The `function(results,status)` bit is where the magic happens. It is run when Google has geocoded the address. Untill then you have nothing to display.

try this:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = fubar;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(1);
        if (marker == null){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
            });
        }
        marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
        alert("Alert 1");
        alert(marker.getPosition());
    });
    alert("Alert 2");
}
```

And you will see that `alert("Alert 2")` appears before `alert("Alert 1")`

Comment: Any recommendations on what the best way to get around this would be?

Comment: You cant get around it, you need to put your logic inside the callback (just like the alerts). If you need to insert/edit text in the website I recommend using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of $.Deferred()

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = fubar;
  var d = $.Deferred();
  var marker;

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(1);
      if (marker == null){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
        });
      }
      marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
      d.resolve();
  });
  d.done(function(){
      document.write(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
```